# Is this cylinder a regular surface?

Tags: differential-geometry, surfaces

Let $C$ be a figure $‘‘8"$ in the $xy$ plane and let $S$ be the cylinder surface over $C$; that is, $$S=\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R^3}:(x,y) \in C \}$$ Is the set $S$ a regular surface?

I know that the answer is no and the reason is because this surface have self-intersections in the levels of the intersection point of $‘‘8"$, but how can I prove this more mathematically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the implicit function theorem it follows that if $S$ is a regular surface and if $p \in S$ then there is a well-defined 2-dimensional tangent plane $T_p S$ with the property that for any differentiable curve $\gamma$ whose image is in $S$ and any $t$ such that $\gamma(t)=p$ then the vector $D\gamma(t)$ is parallel to the plane $T_p S$. In particular the maximum number of linearly independent tangent vectors at $p$ is 2.

But for your figure 8 curve $C$ in the $xy$-plane, letting $X \in C$ be the crossing point, at the point $X$ the curve $C$ has a linearly independent pair of tangent vectors that I'll denote $V_1,V_2$. And so for any point $p$ in $(x,y,z)$-space lying over $X$ you can show that $S$ has three linearly independent tangent vectors at $p$:

- One vector parallel to $V_1$;
- One vector parallel to $V_2$;
- One vector parallel to the $z$-axis.

This contradiction shows that $S$ cannot be a regular surface.

Comment: Thank you! By the way, in the book I'm using, this answer can be used only reading the next section. It can be answer using only the theorems referent to the inverse images of regular values?

Comment: @Jccalab: That's exactly what I mean by referring to the "implicit function theorem", or if you prefer you can just replace that reference with the "inverse function theorem". Those two theorems are very very closely related, by just a few lines of logic.